# Get Page or List - getting Pageable of value null with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I'd like an endpoint that offers to either get a List or a Page. The List would include all available resources. To get the List, the client would have not to provide the `page` and `per_page` parameters.

Unfortunately, I can't detect such a case in my REST controller as Spring Boot will automatically provide a Pageable object with `offset=0` and `size=20` when the client doesn't provide one. **I cannot differentiate between user providing pagination parameters and Spring boot providing default ones.**

I have thus no way to know the client want the full list.

My current solution is to duplicate the endpoint and append the suffix `/all` to the one offering the List. This is less than satisfactory.

Does offering both requirements in a single endpoint make sense ?
If yes, how can I achieve it ? If no, how would you serve the feature ?

Comment: Do you want it to be a list? Can you provide both cases as pages?

Comment: The EntityResponse will always contain a List in the body. The difference when requesting a page is in the headers. When requesting a page, the client will use the headers, when requesting a list, he won't; there isn't even any safe check to do as the client is the one making the request.

Comment: What I meant was, can't you return a page with all available elements in it, when the page params not given?

Comment: The core of the problem is that I can't know whether the parameters are given or not. Spring boot will provide default parameters and I can't differentiate them with user provided ones.
And no, a Page will always have a maximum size of 1000 elements.

Comment: have you found a solutions? same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and check if the params present or not before hitting the controller. Check the code below:

```
    public class PaginationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(Pageable.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {


        String pageParam = webRequest.getParameter("page");
        String sizeParam = webRequest.getParameter("size");
        String sortParam = webRequest.getParameter("sort");


    }
}
```